# JSON Result for Highcharts Data Object in C#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, highcharts, javascriptserializer

I am trying to take a List of a custom class and convert it to JSON in MVC/C#. I have used both json.encode and javascriptserializer to no avail. The json data is shown with &.quot; instead of the single or double quotes. Here's what I believe is the relevant code. This data is going to be used in a highcharts application.

**My Models**

```
public class DataPoint
{
    public double? data { get; set; } //CTDI value
    public DateTime? DateOfScan { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Nmmber{ get; set; }
    public int PersonDatabaseID { get; set; }
    public string EquipmentName{ get; set; }
}

public class PlotData : List<DataPoint>
{
}

public class PlotListModel : List<PlotData>
{
}
```

**My View**

```
foreach (PlotData pd in (PlotListModel) ViewBag.MyData)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var jsData1 = js.Serialize(pd);

    //Or use JSON.Encode
    var jsData2 = Json.Encode(pd);

    string divID = "container" + i;
    <div id='@divID'>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            $(function () {
                var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: '@divID',
                        type: 'colummn'
                    },
                    title: {text: '@divID'},
                    tooltip: {
                        formatter: function () {
                            return 'Extra data: <b>' + this.point.Scanner + '</b>';
                        }
                    },

                    series: [{
                        name: 'Foo',
                        data: ['@jsData1']
                    }]
                });
            });
        </script>
    </div>

    i += 1;
}

When I look at the page source I see the data fields and values surrounded by the encoded quote value - &quot;
```

Comment: You should definitely use Web API to serialize the Data into JSON format and request it from the server via ajax call

Comment: Thanks, Thomas. Any suggestions on a good tutorial on that? Have no idea where to start with that other than a google search.

Comment: http://www.asp.net/web-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a webapi controller and it should contain a method that looks something like this. I am assuming you're using Web Api 2.0 with this example.

```
[Route("api/plotlist")]
[HttpGet]
public PlotListModel GetPlotList() {
    //Here's where you would instantiate and populate your model
    PlotListModel plotList; 

    /*
     * Once your model is instantiated and populated then you can
     * just return it and the serialization will be done for you
     */

    return plotList;
}
```

Once you have that you can then call that method from your client code using ajax. A simple client function might look something like this if you use jQuery.

```
function retreivePlotList() {
    $.getJSON("http://<base url>/api/plotlist", function(data) { 
        //do something with data 
    });
}
```

Comment: Awesome, Casey. Thanks. I will give that a try tonight.

Comment: So I’m having an issue. The method is not being called. I’ve put a stop but it’s never been hit.

Comment: Can you put the url in your browser and have the method called?

Comment: No, I can't. I have localhost/api/plotList and get the 404 error.

Comment: Do you have attribute routing configured correctly? Use this tutorial to double check http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2 . Also make sure this method is in an ApiController. The controller should inherit from the ApiController class

Comment: So you're sure you have attribute routing configured correctly? Are the rest of your views loading properly?

Comment: I have the code working locally so the best guess I can make is there is a problem with how you have set up your web api routing. Do you have other views in another controller that are working?

Comment: None using web api. In fact I  just added web api earlier today. I’ll keep looking. Maybe I just need to remove the controller and add it again?

Comment: Is the register method in a class called WebApiConfig under the App_Start folder? Did you make sure to add GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register); to your Global.asax file?

Comment: Yeah, I checked the GlobalConfig... and it is in Global.asax file and webapi.config is in App_Start

Comment: Not to nitpick but the file should be WebApiConfig.cs. Also, the project is building without any errors or anything? I would focus on making sure that is all setup exactly correct. It may be helpful to create a test project with just a single web api controller and try that. When you create the project in visual studio make sure to check the option for including web api to see exactly how it should be wired up

Comment: Ha! Nitpick all you want. It is .cs. Will do. Thanks a million for all of your help.

Comment: No problem. Let me know if you have better luck

Comment: Well, no luck today in getting the web api to work in my original project. I did get it to work in a new and totally separate project. For clarity I did NOT start off the project using web api. I don’t think I included web api when I first created the project. But, before starting this yesterday I did add web api via adding a web api controller. I’m guessing all of the internal linkage wasn't performed properly in this case, although I’m not really sure what’s left as the config sections etc are all correct. Would it be appropriate to simply add a new project simply for web api needs?

Comment: Change that. Whatever I did I got the api working.... now to get highcharts to recognize the data.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s the web api class

```
public class PlotListController : ApiController
{
    [Route("api/plotlist")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<CTDIDataPoint> GetPlotList()
    {....
```

When I put in localhost/api/plotlist I get the 404 error

Here’s the webapiconfig.

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Comment: Is this an answer, or were you trying to add clarification to your question.